# Why does `exit` suppress errors for Select-Xml?

Tags: powershell, error-handling

I have encountered a (for me) very surprising error-suppressing behaviour in Powershell w.r.t. to the Select-Xml commandlet. For showing the (IMHO) expected behaviour, I first show a minimum example with `Get-Content`:

#### Get-Content

```
try {
    Get-Content -Path "NonExistingFile.txt"
}
finally {
    exit 42
}
```

As expected, this throws an error (incl. message):

```
PS > .\gc-nonexistingfile.ps1
Get-Content : Der Pfad "NonExistingFile.txt" kann nicht gefunden werden, da er nicht
vorhanden ist.
In gc-nonexistingfile.ps1:2 Zeichen:5
+     Get-Content -Path "NonExistingFile.txt"
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (...xistingFile.txt:String) [Get-Content], 
                              ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand

PS > echo $LASTEXITCODE
42
```

#### Select-Xml

If I do the same thing with `Select-Xml`, the error message is swallowed, but **only if I use the `exit` keyword**. If I remove the `exit` line, the error is reported as above:

```
try {
    Select-Xml -Path "NonExistingFile.xml" -XPath "*"
}
finally {
    exit 43  # comment this out to get error message
}
```

Behaviour with exit:

```
PS > .\sx-nonexistingfile.ps1
PS > echo $LASTEXITCODE
43
```

Without exit (calling the commandlet directly for clarity):

```
PS > Select-Xml -Path "NonExistingFile.xml" -XPath "*"
Select-Xml : Der Pfad "NonExistingFile.xml" kann nicht gefunden werden, da er nicht
vorhanden ist.
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1
+ Select-Xml -Path "NonExistingFile.xml" -XPath "*"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (...xistingFile.xml:String) [Select-Xml],
                              ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectXmlCommand
```

---

#### Question

My question: why the difference? And: how can I have `Select-Xml` throw its error visibly, despite me using `exit` to end my script?

Comment: `try` only swallows _terminating_ errors - `Get-Content` throws a _non-terminating_ error message when it can't find the target file. Add `-ErrorAction Stop` to `Get-Content` to make it behave the same

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: thanks, but I would rather like `Select-Xml` to behave like `Get-Content`: I want to see an error, not swallow it.

Comment: Then either 1) don't run it inside `try`, or 2) add a `catch` block to re-throw it, or 3) run `Select-Xml` with `-ErrorAction Continue`

Comment: 1) That point is actually interesting, because I do not currently see why removing the `try...finally` *shows* the error message for `Select-Xml`. 2) Yes, that's my current "best" work-around. But I would like to better understand why I need it here. 3) No, that does not make any difference for me: it still won't show any error message. The "3)" is actually the main cause for my question. I seem to not understand/see/appreciate some significant detail/aspect/concept here, that's why I phrased my question so verbosely.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen if you clarify the difference (non-terminating vs. terminating) is actually in the error-throwing behaviour of both commandlets, I would be happily accepting this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [@Mathias R. Jessen's suggestion in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54405307/why-does-exit-suppress-errors-for-select-xml?noredirect=1#comment95622635_54405307), the best solution I settled on is a `catch` block in the script:

1. Introduce a custom error reporting function
2. Use it in an *explicit catch block* to rethrow any exceptions

With that:

```
function Report-Error ($Error)
{
    $FormatString = "{0} : {1}`n{2}`n" +
                    "    + CategoryInfo          : {3}`n" +
                    "    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : {4}`n"
    $ErrorFields = $Error.InvocationInfo.MyCommand.Name,
                   $Error.ErrorDetails.Message,
                   $Error.InvocationInfo.PositionMessage,
                   $Error.CategoryInfo.ToString(),
                   $Error.FullyQualifiedErrorId
    Write-Host -Foreground Red -Background Black ($FormatString -f $ErrorFields)
}
```

The script becomes:

```
try {
    Select-Xml -Path "NonExistingFile.xml" -XPath "*"
}
catch {
    Report-Error $_
}
finally {
    exit 43
}
```